# Called court to learn status of warrant but there’s no record of one

Tags: arrest, colorado, court-records, warrant

I was hoping to resolve a warrant, as I should most definitely have one, in Colorado Springs, El Paso County.  However, I called the county's warrant office and the clerk said they did not have me in their system for a warrant. This is over a matter which occurred 2 years ago. Does this mean there is for certain no warrant, or that they are negligent in simply updating their database?

Comment: What jurisdiction (*country, province, principality, state, county etc*) does your question relate to?

Comment: This was in Colorado Springs, CO. El Paso County

Comment: Is there any way you could find out which court may have issued the warrant so you could ask there?

Comment: That was the court I initially contacted, if I’m understanding your question correctly. I think I will ask for an attorneys assistance to see what happened.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, didn't realise that the WO was part of the court. Getting an attorney seems to be the way forward.

Comment: Is it possible that it was a municipal court warrant rather than a county or district court warrant? Municipal court records are not integrated with state court records.